# Как прописать путь к файлу в jq?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть карта от гугл, я прописал путь к своей метке, она картинка.

Вот код

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'VR-galaxy',
    icon: 'img/меп.png'
  });
}
```

Все супер, после переноса сайта на вордпрес, иконка перестала отображаться, как правильно прописать путь?

Сейчас местоположение файлов не менялось, хелп.

Answer (score 2):

В url для icon указывается абсолютный путь от корня ваших папок (тогда путь начинается со `/`) или относительный от папки, где находится скрипт (тогда путь **не** начинается со `/`).

Если, например, скрипт находится в

```
/wp-content/themes/моя-тема/js/script.js
```

в картинка в

```
/wp-content/themes/моя-тема/img/меп.png
```

то относительный путь надо указать так:

```
icon: '../img/меп.png'
```

Comment: скрипт в файле в папке /wp-content/themes/моя-тема/файл, а    картинка в /wp-content/themes/моя-тема/img/картинка

Comment: Решил проблему, почему то не грузило файл пока у него было имя на рус, переим на анг все заработало, всем спасибо